# Problem inflating layout in a custom Class

Tags: android

I'm trying to inflate a xml layout, but I'm having problems doing it.

I created a custom class named "DebugHelper" where I received

```
class DebugHelper {    
    void drawGrid(final Application context, final View anchorview) {
    
       map.setOnPolygonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener(){
        public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

                    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // 1
                    View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classification_map, null); 
                    TextView a = (TextView) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

                    Toast.makeText(context, a.getText(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

    });


}
```

With this I can access the elements of the other view which is part of what I want but the view in particular doesn't show up. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have not used `theInflatedView` ? Don't you need to add it on some container ?

Comment: you are not setting the view (theInflatedView) Hence you are unable to get the view. return new anchorview(inflator).

Answer (score 0):

anchorview.addView(theInflatedView) can help you?